# Is there any way to make semi-transparent window without using UpdateLayeredWindow

Tags: winapi, user-interface, direct2d

I'm programming for Win7+ and using Direct2D for drawing. UpdateLayeredWindow requires a HDC, which means I'd better create a WICRenderTarget(not GPU accelerated). Is there any way to make a semi-transparent window without using UpdateLayeredWindow?

Answer (score 0):

There are only two API functions for rendering layered windows: [`UpdateLayeredWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`SetLayeredWindowAttributes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

`UpdateLayeredWindow()` requires you to render your window contents to your own in-memory bitmap `HDC` which the OS then displays when needed.

`SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` relies on the traditional `WM_PAINT` model of requiring you to render to an OS-provided `HDC` instead, which is implemented as an in-memory bitmap `HDC` that the OS applies effects to after your rendering is finished.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does it mean a layered window has been the only way to implement a semi-transparent window until now?

Comment: Layered windows were introduced in Windows 2000, so they have been around a long time. They are the preferred way to make transparent and/or alpha-blended *floating* windows (child windows cannot be created as layered windows prior to Windows 8). `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` is easier to code for, as it works with existing `WM_PAINT`-based code. `UpdateLayeredWindow()` is more efficient but harder to code for, as it does not use `WM_PAINT` at all. So the choice is yours which method you want to use, but you have to use one or the other.